# iOS Email keyboard customize

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, customization

In my app, I have a UITextField using UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress.

There is space key in bottom centre. I think space key is no needed.

So I'd like to change the key to gmail.com or hotmail.com.
Is it possible?

Even if it's possible, Apple will approve it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instead of using `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress` you could design your own input view (which I suppose in your case would be whatever keyboard you design) and then set that as the input view of your text field.

[Sample code can be seen in this tutorial](http://karthik-prabhu.blogspot.com/2012/09/storyboard-in-ios.html), and [more information can be found in this official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to change just text of space key to gmail.com, not view. To change it, should I customize all keys?